# How does SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() work?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` obtains the currently authenticated principal, or an authentication request token, but in which context should we use it? Is it thread safe? For example, if we use a static helper method like:

```
public static UserEntity getCurrentUser() {
        return (UserEntity)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
}
```

Will it be safe to use? Or should we only use it under request scoped bean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Spring Security Document:

> By default the SecurityContextHolder uses a ThreadLocal to store these
> details, which means that the SecurityContext is always available to
> methods in the same thread, even if the SecurityContext is not
> explicitly passed around as an argument to those methods. Using a
> ThreadLocal in this way is quite safe if care is taken to clear the
> thread after the present principal’s request is processed. Spring
> Security’s FilterChainProxy ensures that the SecurityContext is always
> cleared.

As per [this blog](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/threadlocal.html#:%7E:text=The%20Java%20ThreadLocal%20class%20enables,see%20each%20other%27s%20ThreadLocal%20variables.) :

> The Java ThreadLocal class enables you to create variables that can
> only be read and written by the same thread. Thus, even if two threads
> are executing the same code, and the code has a reference to the same
> ThreadLocal variable, the two threads cannot see each other's
> ThreadLocal variables. Thus, the Java ThreadLocal class provides a
> simple way to make code thread safe that would not otherwise be so.

Putting these together answers the question that is it safe to have a static util method to get the currently logged in user from `SecurityContextHolder`, Which is, ***yes it is safe***.